# Are there any large 4K TVs on the market which have DisplayPort ports?

Tags: hdmi, television, displays, 4k, display-port

Are there any large 4K TVs on the market which have DisplayPort ports? A quick Google search for this does not turn up many results. I found that many people have said that HDMI is the standard for TVs and nobody wants DisplayPort or [USB Type-C](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/8648/are-there-any-large-4k-tvs-on-the-market-which-have-usb-type-c-inputs). However, I definitely do want this feature.

Rather than debating whether it's in demand or not, I would like to know: Are there any available?

Comment: Panasonic [AX900](http://shop.panasonic.com/support-only/TC-65AX900U.html) has 1 DisplayPort input.

Comment: @Alpha3031 It appears that the Panasonic AX900 is no longer sold anywhere.

Comment: What do you want the feature for?

Comment: The [Philips BDM4065UC/00](https://www.amazon.com/Philips-BDM4065UC-Resolution-Speakers-DisplayPort/dp/B00SCX78JS) does, but it's technically a 40" monitor.