# What are some good large 4K TVs with plenty of HDMI 2.0a/b or 2.1 ports?

Tags: hdmi, television, 4k, hdtv

I'm looking to buy a new 4K TV.

- It should be fairly large, above 50", but I don't care if it's 55" or 65" or whatever.
- The TV should support at least 3840x2160 at 60Hz with HDR on at least 2 inputs.
- As how there [aren't any TVs with DisplayPort](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/8296/are-there-any-large-4k-tvs-on-the-market-which-have-displayport-ports), the next best thing is HDMI, I want at least 5 HDMI ports, at least 2 of them being HDMI 2.1 or 2.0a/b and supporting 4K input at 60Hz.
- I do not care if it is a "smart" TV or not.
- Obviously inexpensive is preferable.

If you know TV that comes close to meeting these requirements but not quite (like only 4 HDMI ports or just under 50") then feel free to post it too.

Comment: The requirement for lots of HDMI ports suggests that you're not using an AV receiver.  Is that true?  Normally, the AV receiver would have lots of HDMI ports for various goodies and then you'd have a single HDMI cable from the receiver to the TV.

Comment: No, I want to use the TV remote for switching inputs. I don't need a separate box. How is that "normally" what people do? I've never seen it before.

Comment: The AV receiver, in addition to allowing multiple source devices (Roku, PS3, Blu Ray player, Cable/Fiber set top box), the AV receiver will drive various standards of surround sound speakers (at something like 100 watts per channel or whatever).  This is something a TV cannot do and why most people use a receiver (something has to drive those speakers).

Comment: How well do receivers play with HDCP? Wouldn't handshaking be problematic with a device that accepts multiple inputs and can even send the sound elsewhere?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that question.

Answer (score 1):

Like @mbmast says in the comments, it might be more logical to have a full AV Receiver. That is the device that is meant to do this.

But as for a TV, I think that the 2017 Visio P55-E1 ticks most, if not all, your requirements:

https://www.vizio.com/tvs/pseries/p55e1.html