# Are there any large 4K TVs on the market which have USB Type-C inputs?

Tags: usb, hdmi, television, 4k, display-port

Are there any large 4K TVs on the market which have USB Type-C inputs? USB Type-C can carry a DisplayPort signal so a TV could use it for the video signal. A quick Google search for this does not turn up many results. I found that many people have said that HDMI is the standard for TVs and nobody wants USB Type-C or [DisplayPort](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/8296/are-there-any-large-4k-tvs-on-the-market-which-have-displayport-ports) on TVs. However, I definitely do want this feature.

Rather than debating whether it's in demand or not, I would like to know: Are there any available?

Comment: I'm tempted to say that this should be merged with your DisplayPort question, since USB-C carries a DisplayPort signal.

Comment: However, they are different physical connectors. I believe two questions is justified, though they are related, so I put links to each other in them.

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ I guess. Still confused as to why you need a DisplayPort signal.